# filtering / sorting on difference between two values as contained in nested array (using script filter and doc values only)

Tags: elasticsearch

Easier to illustrate my question with a usecase so let's us the [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) from the elasticsearch guide.

This lists a product. Each product has a nested array containing resellers that sell said product:

```
    {
        ...

        "product" : {
            "properties" : {
                "resellers" : { 
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "name" : { "type" : "text" },
                        "price" : { "type" : "double" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I do the following if at all possible?

- Filter all products where storeA is cheaper than storeB. E.g.: `product.resellers[name=storeA].price < product.resellers[name=storeB].price`
- Order products by difference between price of storeA and store B

This likely needs a script filter and order filter respectively, but not sure how I would go about this. Moreover, these types of queries are used frequently so performance is important. Therefore I probably need to stick with docValues instead of resorting to `_source`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely possible and you can do it like this:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "inline": "def store1 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store1}; def store2 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store2}; (store1 != null && store2 != null) ? store1.price - store2.price : 0",
        "lang": "groovy",
        "params": {
          "store1": "storeA",
          "store2": "storeB"
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "def store1 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store1}; def store2 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store2}; (store1 != null && store2 != null) ? store1.price < store2.price : false",
              "lang": "groovy",
              "params": {
                "store1": "storeA",
                "store2": "storeB"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The sort script looks like this:

```
def store1 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store1}; 
def store2 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store2}; 
(store1 != null && store2 != null) ? store1.price - store2.price : 0
```

The filter script is a bit similar and looks like this:

```
def store1 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store1}; 
def store2 = _source.resellers.find{it.name == store2}; 
(store1 != null && store2 != null) ? store1.price < store2.price : false
```

Both scripts take two parameters in input, namely the names of the reseller stores you want to compare.

**UPDATE**

Somehow I forgot to explain why it's not possible to do it with doc values. Doc values are effectively the inverse of the inverted index, i.e. to each document are mapped the tokens present inside that document. This coupled with the fact that nested documents are stored as standalone (yet hidden) documents in the index, the doc values for a document like the one below

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "product": "Water",
  "resellers": [
    {
      "name": "storeA",
      "price": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "storeB",
      "price": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

would look like this:

```
Document        | Values
----------------+---------------------------
1  (top-level)  | water
1a (1st nested} | storea, 20
1b (2nd nested} | storeb, 30
```

Looking at the above table, and since scripts are executed in the context of each document (whether top-level or nested), it becomes evident that when accessing to doc values within a script will only yield the values of that document, and hence it is not possible to compare them with values from another document.

When accessing the source, we're effectively iterating over the `resellers` array and it is thus possible to compare the values among them and yield something that is useful in your context.

Comment: Op here. Agree this would work, but as per original question I'm looking for a solution involving doc values instead of using `_source` since using `_source` requires (the equivalent of) a full-table scan which would be too slow for my purposes. If this isn't possible, I'd take a well explained edit as to the 'why not' as well. Thanks

Comment: You're right, somehow I forgot to include why it is not possible to do this with doc values.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a marketplace problem. So i would separate products by their master product id's - so products can have different descriptions, propertys etc. - and add them Priority to sort and filter.

```
 {
        ...

        "product" : {
            "properties" : {
                "masterProduct" : "int",
                "priority" : "int",
                "resellers" : { 

                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "name" : { "type" : "text" },
                        "price" : { "type" : "double" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me explain how; 
First,

*product.resellers[name=storeA].price < roduct.resellers[name=storeB].price*

I guess this problem raised because of you want to show the cheapest product in the search result. So i think you should have all resellers price while indexing products.

And if you know the cheapest while indexing make it's priority a positive number like 1. And multiply other products with -1, so you can sort them in the product detail cheap to expensive. 
This solves the second problem (*Order products by difference between price of storeA and store B*).

After all you got positive priorities and negative priorities in your index. And all you can make a filter by priority > 0 returns you the cheapest products. So by priority if any reseller wants to be the top off the search result or promote itself you can do it by increasing priorty

Comment: It's not a 'market place' problem. I need to compare arbitrary shops against eachother to populate a stats-dashboard. If it was however, yours would be a rather elegant solution.